# k8s: unexpected behaviour from PersistentVolume

Tags: kubernetes

I have set up a `PersistantVolume`for my k8s pods since I want to use the folder to save some files in it.  To reproduce the problem, you can find bellow the code I am using to deploy everything I use.

File 1:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: local-storage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

File 2 (configuring the pv):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-volume
spec:
  storageClassName: local-storage
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  local:
    path: “/home/pi/data”
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
            - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
              operator: In
              values:
                - pi
```

File 3 (claiming the pv):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: local-storage
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3Gi
```

File 4 (deployment file):

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-deployment
  labels:
    app: test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: test
        image: [some_image]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: pv-storage
          mountPath: "/mnt"
      volumes:
      - name: pv-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: pv-claim
```

As you can see, in file 2, I am defining that the local folder, I want to be mounted in my pods, is located at `"/home/pi/data"`. The folder is located on my RPi where I deploy the pods. In it, I have created a `test.txt` file. Furthermore, in file 4, I have defined that I want the volume to be mounted at `"/mnt"`.

Nevertheless, once I deploy everything, I see that:

1. the test file from the local storage (RPi) is not shown in `"/mnt"` in the created pod.
2. If I create a file in the container in "/mnt" and delete the pod and create a new one, the file is still in there. Which tells me that the PersistantVolume is working in a certain way.

My questions are:

1. Why isn't the test file from my local storage not being copied?
2. If the persistent volume is working, then where are the file being stored? Since at no point anything is being created in `"/home/pi/data"`.

Comment: How did you setup kubernetes on the pi?

Comment: Has the user inside the container permission to read the file? E.g: if the user inside the container has UID 1001, the pi user has UID 1000, and the test.txt has 400 permissions, you will not see the file inside the container.